# bootstrap grid align elements horizontally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, alignment, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a quick question about Bootstrap Grid.

If I have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    Some header here
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="input-small" />
                    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

How would you pull the inputfield more to the left, so it has about 5px margin to my "Header" text?

My div with the text obviously has a width, so I can't just pull the input closer to the text.
I could change the class to col-md-1, but then my text would be forced on two lines.

I've set up a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/62kLr/
You might have to resize your window, to see the alignment correctly.

/BR
Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `label` instead of separate column...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <label>Some header here</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-small">
                    <input type="submit" value="ok">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/117582

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot for the tip :)
Sometimes you just need somebody else eyes on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the col-sm-2 , col-xs-2 features in your grid.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                Some header here
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="input-small" />
      <input type="submit" value="ok" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: col-md is for medium sized screens, use col-xs for small screen devices. the given code is the working code.